# php change the name to construct an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, extend

Is it possible in php to change the name used to create an associative array? I am using mongo in php but it's getting confusing using `array()` in both cases of indexed arrays and associative arrays. I know you can do it in javascript by stealing the Array.prototype methods but can it be done in php my extending the native object? it would be much easier if it was `array()` and `assoc()` they would both create the same thing though.

EDIT -------

following Tristan's lead, I made this simple function to easily 
write in json in php. It will even take on variable from within 
your php as the whole thing is enclosed in quotes.

```
$one = 'newOne';
$json = "{
    '$one': 1,
    'two': 2
}";

// doesn't work as json_decode expects quotes.
print_r(json_decode($json));

// this does work as it replaces all the single quotes before 
// using json decode.
print_r(jsonToArray($json));

function jsonToArray($str){
    return json_decode(preg_replace('/\'/', '"', $str), true);
}
```

Comment: Read about how PHP arrays work. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. All Arrays in PHP are actually ordered maps.

Comment: And what's the reason for this?

Comment: will do @Tristan. the reason is just to be able to make sense of the embedded arrays in mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP there is no "name used to create an associative array" or "name used to create an indexed array". PHP Arrays are ordered maps like in many other scripting languages.

This means that you can use an array whichever way you please.

If you wanted an indexed array..

```
$indexedArray = array();

$indexedArray[] = 4; // Append a value to the array.

echo $indexedArray[0]; // Access the value at the 0th index.
```

Or even..

```
$indexedArray = [0, 10, 12, 8];

echo $indexedArray[3]; // Outputs 8.
```

If you want to use non integer keys with your array, you simply specify them.

```
$assocArray = ['foo' => 'bar'];

echo $assocArray['foo']; // Outputs bar.
```

Comment: nice, I never knew you could use square bracket notation, I will use square brackets as associative and array() as indexed.

Comment: Yep! "As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with []." Looks so much better than before :P

Comment: Yep, they've got JSON, http://www.php.net/json. It works well also, you simply encode an object using `$str = json_encode($obj);`, and decode it with `$obj = json_decode($str);`.

Comment: that's what I use for ajax, but It's probably a little harder to do it  straight php having to stringify everything manually, than using `array(['associative' => 'array'], ['another' => 'associativeArray']) @Tristan

Comment: You'll get the hang of it, haha.

Comment: thanks for the suggesting to use json_decode, I added a method to my php that let's be write is a json syntax.